# Why does Stiles tell them to go to Canaan and not any other place from the arrival list?

Tags: plot-explanation, teen-wolf-tv

In *Teen Wolf* S06E05, Stiles got one chance to talk to his friends and he tells them to go to Canaan, but why? Why Canaan and not any other city? There were many cities in the chart with "ARRIVED" status:

[image]